# webdriver can´t find elements under DefinitionList

Tags: webdriver, element

I try to find an textbox in a page to send a value but the WebDriver can´t find it. 
I tried to find using id, name, xpath but none worked

here´s a snippet of the code

```
<dl class="user-info-fields">
  <dd>
    <input id="user_cpf" type="text" size="30" name="user[cpf]">
  </dd>
</dl>
```

There´s a lot of info that I tried to find in an DL tag, but the WebDriver never find it.

There´s some limitation on WebDriver API to treat an element under DL or I making something wrong?

Comment: "*I tried to find using id, name, xpath but none worked*". What commands exactly have you tried? Has the page loaded when you are trying to find element?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what you've already tried, since you didn't supply any code.  But did you try finding it by ID?

In C#, this would look like:

```cs
IWebElement element = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("user_cpf"));
```

Likewise, it is also possible that the above method will fail if the page has not yet loaded.  WebDriver has many built in methods for providing waits (http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

The easiest way to test this would be to do a simple Thread.Sleep(5000)* right before you're trying to find the element.

**In production code, try to avoid hardcoded waits as much as possible.*